DAX calculation in Retention Analysis is Inaccurate
I am using DAX in PowerBI to calculate a quarterly retention rate.  I'm using the following measures to calculate starting head count, ending head count and total exits for each interval of time (quarters).
Starting Head Count = CALCULATE([AllStaffCount],FILTER(BelongingFactTable,BelongingFactTable[HireDate]<FIRSTDATE(MyDateTable[Date]) && (BelongingFactTable[ExitClean]= BLANK() || BelongingFactTable[ExitClean]>= FIRSTDATE(MyDateTable[Date]) )))


Ending Head Count = CALCULATE([AllStaffCount],FILTER(BelongingFactTable,BelongingFactTable[HireDate]<=FIRSTDATE(MyDateTable[Date]) && ( BelongingFactTable[ExitClean]= BLANK() || BelongingFactTable[ExitClean]>= LASTDATE(MyDateTable[Date]) )))


EXITS = 
CALCULATE( [AllStaffCount],
    FILTER(BelongingFactTable,   BelongingFactTable[ExitClean]>=FIRSTDATE(MyDateTable[Date]) && BelongingFactTable[ExitClean]<=LASTDATE(MyDateTable[Date]) && BelongingFactTable[ExitClean] <> DATE(2049,1,1) ))


The results are in the screenshot below.  You can see that the count of exits (Ending minus Starting counts) does NOT always yield a correct answer (yellow highlight).
Can anyone offer a solution or advice to address this problem?
Thanks!

Can  you share a sample .pbix?

what's the easiest way to create one?

Put the minimal data you need in a .pbix that shows the issue and upload to a site. Then you can share the link here.

what site is best/useful for this purpose?  thx!

Pick any. You can share from google, onedrive or any site of your choosing.

What exactly is your question? If you want the difference, simply define Diff = [Ending Head Count] - [Starting Head Count]. This is different from EXITS if there are also hires during that same period.

I've used the Diff equation you mentioned @Alexis, but it too has errors. So, my question regards why the Exit count is inaccurate.

@Ben, I can't determine, in general, what you consider correct and what you consider an error. Please provide a comparison of both what you expect and what you're getting.

@davidebacci  See a de-identified minimal file here:  https://github.com/bac3917/Cauldron/blob/master/EmpRetentionShareable.pbix

@AlexisOlson A correct answer would be 543-532 = 9 (for the second row)

There is too much logic there for me to debug and quite a few business rules I don't have background knowledge of but simply why are you not just doing [Starting Head Count] - [Ending Head Count] which gives the correct count of exits?

I suggest reading up here too: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-the-difference-between-lastdate-and-max-in-dax/

Your date table needs to span full calendar years BTW otherwise any time intelligence you use will be unreliable.

@Ben 543-532 = 11. Where does 9 come from?

@AlexisOlson  My bad!  But you can see the issue that PBI is giving me 12. If I use simply Diff = [Ending Head Count] - [Starting Head Count] some rows still have incorrect answers. See the pbix I shared above if you would
